# Ansible remote templates

Tags: ansible

I have templates for configuration files stored in my project's repositories. What I would like to do is use Ansible's template module to create a configuration file using that template on the remote server, after the project has been cloned from the repository.

Looking at the documentation for the [template](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/template_module.html) module it appears that the `src` attribute only supports local files.

I wanted to avoid storing the configuration template with my Ansible playbook as it makes more sense for me to keep these project specific templates within the project repository.

Is there an alternative to the template module that I could use?

Comment: Why not allow Ansible to pull your other repo as well?

Comment: Ansible clones the repo to the remote server. Once it has cloned, I need to make changes using the template which was in the repo and is now on the remote machine.

Comment: Yes but why can't Ansible pull your repo locally as well as cloning it on the target host? Then it could use the template functionality. Your alternative is to use `fetch` to pull the the template back from the host but it feels like a less clean method to me.

Comment: Note that this is a "won't fix" issue: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/65778

Comment: In some cases i clone using Ansible a repo to the remote host which contains their own `*.j2` templates, so later on on my other Ansible tasks I just use `remote_src: yes` so it knows to lookup the src in the remote host ( aka: my git repo ) vs my local directory

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You've got two options here if your template is going to be on the remote host.

Firstly, you can use the [fetch](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/fetch_module.html) module which works as pretty much the opposite to the [copy](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html) module to bring the template back after cloning the repo on the remote host.

A playbook for this might look something like:

```
- name : clone repo on remote hosts
  git  :
    repo : {{ git_repo_src }}
    dest : {{ git_repo_dest }}

- name     : fetch template from single remote host
  run_once : true
  fetch    :
    src             : {{ template_path }}/{{ template_file }}
    dest            : /tmp/{{ template_file }}
    flat            : yes
    fail_on_missing : yes

- name     : template remote hosts
  template :
    src   : /tmp/{{ template_file }}
    dest  : {{ templated_file_dest }}
    owner : {{ templated_file_owner }}
    group : {{ templated_file_group }}
    mode  : {{ templated_file_mode }}
```

The fetch task uses [`run_once`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#run-once) to make sure that it only bothers copying the template from the first host it runs against. Assuming all these hosts in your play are the getting the same repo then this should be fine but if you needed to make sure that it copied from a very specific host then you could combine it with [`delegate_to`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation).

Alternatively you could just have Ansible clone the repo locally and use it directly with something like:

```
- name : clone repo on remote hosts
  git  :
    repo : {{ git_repo_src }}
    dest : {{ git_repo_dest }}

- name       : clone repo on Ansible host
  hosts      : localhost
  connection : local
  git  :
    repo : {{ git_repo_src }}
    dest : {{ git_repo_local_dest }}

- name     : template remote hosts
  template :
    src   : {{ template_local_src }}
    dest  : {{ templated_file_dest }}
    owner : {{ templated_file_owner }}
    group : {{ templated_file_group }}
    mode  : {{ templated_file_mode }}
```